# Python and remove duplicates in list of lists regardless of order within lists

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have searched and haven't quite found the same question as mine.  I want to remove duplicates from a list of lists in python; however, I don't care what order the values are in the list.  They way I am doing it currently is too time-consuming.

What I want to do:

```
A = [[1,2,3] , [2,3,4] , [3,4,5] , [3,2,4]]
```

I want to search through A and remove all duplicates.  The duplicates here would be [2,3,4] and [3,2,4].  This would reduce down to:

```
smaller_A = [[1,2,3] , [2,3,4], [3,4,5]]
```

How I am currently doing it:

```
todelete = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(A)):
        if set(A[i]) == set(A[j]):
           todelete.append(j)

todelete = sorted(set(todelete))

smaller_A= [A[i] for i in range(len(A)) if i not in todelete]
```

Again, this works, but it is very time consuming when my lists are large.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Frozensets](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) are perfect for cases like this, when you need to nest sets:

```
>>> A = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [3,2,4]]
>>> smaller_A = {frozenset(x) for x in A}
>>> smaller_A
{frozenset({1, 2, 3}), frozenset({2, 3, 4}), frozenset({3, 4, 5})}
```

To convert back to lists, you can do this:

```
>>> [list(x) for x in smaller_A]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

This won't conserve the order of your lists or the elements inside them.  (Although it didn't make a difference here.)

If you do need to preserve order, you can iterate over `A` while keeping track of frozensets seen so far:

```
>>> A = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [3,2,4]]
>>> seen = set()
>>> smaller_A = []
>>> for x in A:
...     if frozenset(x) not in seen:
...         smaller_A.append(x)
...         seen.add(frozenset(x))
...
>>> smaller_A
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

(This isn't optimized; ideally, you'd only call `frozenset(x)` once and store the result in a variable.)

Comment: This is great!  I have not come across frozenset.  I did need to preserve some sort of order, so I used the small loop you provided.  However, I didn't quite understand what isn't optimized.  Are you saying before the if statement I would have fs = frozenset(x), then use fs for the next two lines?  Thanks!

Comment: For fun, this sped up my code (containing a list of 5040 lists) from 24.1s to .0067s!  Wow!  Props to flornquake!

Answer (score 1):

you can do a trick with sorting this way

```
for i in range(len(A)): A[i].sort()
```

then remove duplicates